# Is it possible to have "does not equal to a number" in Python

Tags: python

Hi my code is meant to read a text file and print the character count and the specific word for a chosen index by the user.

```
def main():
    filename = input("Enter filename: \n")
    print(f"The total number of characters in the file {filename} is: {character_count(filename)} \n")
    while True:
        n = int(input(f"\nEnter a index number that you want to check in the file or type 'S' to stop: "))
        if n == 'S':
            break
        else:
            print(f"\nThe index of {n} in the file is {find_word(filename, n)}")
```

Everything works smoothly except the break part. If I enter any letter I get an error saying its not a integer and my code doesn't work. If I input any number the code works as intended. I had to include the int(input) part as my else print statement was giving me nothing without it (It would just print "The index of 7 [random number I chose] in the file is "). How can I have both features working? I was thinking doing

```
n !=
```

as I wanted to have anything that does not equal an integer but I don't know what goes on the opposite end of !=

Comment: Do you want to check for any number, any integer, or a single digit?

Comment: Why do you need to convert to `int` before the `else`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't convert the input to `int` immediately. Now you can compare it to a string.

```
def main():
    filename = input("Enter filename: \n")
    print(f"The total number of characters in the file {filename} is: {character_count(filename)} \n")
    while True:
        n = input(f"\nEnter a index number that you want to check in the file or type 'S' to stop: ")
        if n == 'S':
            break
        
        n = int(n)
        print(f"\nThe index of {n} in the file is {find_word(filename, n)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking with str.isnumeric:

```
    while True:
        user_input = input(f"\nEnter a index number that you want to check in the file or type 'S' to stop: ")
        if user_input.isnumeric():
            // Do stuff here 
        elif user_input == 'S':
            break
```